# ReactJS MaterialUI Checkboxes- setting state within onCheck()

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

Using `material-ui 0.15.3` and `react 15.3.0`.

I have a Checkbox component and want to use `this.setState` within its `onCheck` function.

It became apparent pretty quickly that I had to manually pass something into the Checkbox's `checked` prop. If I don't, then I cannot use setState. If I try to do so, then the visual component of the checkbox wont update. E.g. I click the checkbox and it stays empty. **My first question is why? Why can't I keep this as an uncontrolled component? Why must I pass something into the `checked` prop?**

```
    <Checkbox
    label="1"
    style={styles.checkbox}
    onCheck={this.handleCheck.bind(this)}
    checked={this.state.box1} // if this is not supplied then I cannot use setState within handleCheck()
```

handleCheck():

```
  handleCheck(event, checked) {
    this.setState({
        box1: checked 
        someState: someValue 
    });
 }
```

Now I have multiple checkboxes, **so my second question is, how can I structure this so it is as clean as possible? Will I need to have a separate state variable for each checkbox with individual handleCheck() functions?** I feel like that would get messy very quickly. e.g. (state for box1, box2, box3 etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Will I need to have a separate state variable for each checkbox?

Yes, but it doesn't need to be cumbersome. It could be an array of ids that correspond to a particular checkbox.

> Will I need to have a separate handleCheck() functions?

Certainly not, a single function will do. Just pass the id along.

Here's an example imagining you have a variable number of checkboxes:

```
handleCheck(id) {
  let found = this.state.activeCheckboxes.includes(id)
  if (found) {
    this.setState({ 
      activeCheckboxes: this.state.activeCheckboxes.filter(x => x !== id)
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({ 
      activeCheckboxes: [ ...this.state.activeCheckboxes, id ]
    })
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.aBunchOfCheckboxes.map(checkbox =>
        <Checkbox
          label={checkbox.label}
          onCheck={() => this.handleCheck(checkbox.id)}
          checked={this.state.activeCheckboxes.includes(id)}
        />
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  so have a state array that represents which checkboxes are active? what is `this.state.aBunchOfCheckboxes' supposed to represent?

Comment: It's just to illustrate how this would work with any number of checkboxes. You don't need that for this work.

Comment: thanks a bunch. how do i go about attaching an id/label to checkbox though? can you show me an example?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking.. I put a `label` prop in my example

Comment: @azium can you please post a working example for this materialui- checkbox, it will be helpful. thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is why? Why can't I keep this as an uncontrolled component? Why must I pass something into the checked prop?

The checkbox needs the `checked` property to decide whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked. When `checked` receives `true`, the checkbox is shown as checked and when it receives `false`, it's kept unchecked. If you don't pass in a value, how is it supposed to know whether to show a checked checkbox or an unchecked checkbox?